# Nodejs express validate user input and redirect

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have a simple nodejs page with textbox and a button. After the user clicks the button, I want to read the user input and validate it. If the input is not OK then stay on the same page and if input is OK then redirect to another page.

I have jade file and it's corresponding js file. What's the best way to do it.

Basically I want to read the input from authcode and process it

### Here is my jade code

```
doctype html
html(lang="en", class="no-js")
head
    meta(charset="utf-8")
    meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/foundation/css/normalize.css")
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/foundation/css/foundation.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/style.css')
body
    center
      h1 Software License Expired
      h3
        | Please renew the contract to use the system.
        h3
          | Machine Code
          br
        input(type='text', name='machcode', value=machcode, disabled='')
        br
        br
        h3
          | Enter Auth Code
          br
        input(type='text', name='authcode')
        br
        br
        button(type='button', onclick="alert('Hurray')") Renew
```

### This is the JS page

```
router.get('/', function(req, res)
{
    utils.dump("expiry::get - " + __filename);
    res.render('expiry', 
    { 
        current_page: 'toolbar_expiry_page', 
        title: 'EXPIRY_PAGE',
        machcode: "some code"
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Are you using the `body-parser` module?

Comment: Yes I am using body-parser

Answer (score 0):

I took some of my own work, hope this sheds some light on the situation:

**Server-side validation**

```
router.post('/login/', function(req, res) {

    var input = req.body;

    // Check if both fields have been filled in
    if(input.email === '' || input.password === '') {
        res.render('dashboard/login', { error: 'Please enter a email / password'})
    }
    else {
        res.render('dashboard/loggedin')
    }
})
```

**Client-side validation**

```
form.on('submit', function(e) {
/* validate code here */
    if(!valid) {
        sendError(); /* generate error at real time */
        return false;
    }
})
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: I know what you are saying but I am not sure all this tie-up together. Basically after user clicks the Renew button, the onClick is called. So should I assign JS function to the onClick or shall I assign the routing page to the onClick?

Comment: That depends, do you wish to check client or server side? Client side can be avoided, but server side requires ajax / reload in order to work.